# Scene Renders well in Eevee but Textures are all blank in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I'm having a problem that's best illustrated with images.

Here is my render in Eevee:
[image: My render in Eevee]

And here it is in Cycles:
[image: My image with blank textures]

The compositor is very basic, with the image plugged into the viewer and composite nodes. I'd love to know what additional settings to look at. Sorry I can't share this for diagnosis; it's huge and has a ton of cross links with protected assets.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be happy to provide further data to help diagnosis.

Comment: Maybe if you're in Cycles you've chosen a material in the View Layers panel > Override? Or your material are all plugged into an Output that is set to Eevee (but it would appear black)? You could just share one part of your object...

Comment: A great many of these meshes are instances from my asset browser, but the few that are regular ol' meshes share the quality of being principled BSDF with material output set to All. I have also confirmed that the instanced meshes are, with almost no exception, standard PBR's set to All.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This will probably help some future person with the same issue so here is what you do:

Go to the VIEW layer and scroll down to the bottom where OVERRIDE is and make sure you didn't accidentally put some stupid thing in that field. Like I did.

Comment: well, that's what I told you  ;)   ....

Comment: DOH! I didn't realize it. Thanks! Sorry!